# How to store multimedia files in android app such as multimedia files

Tags: android

In android app i am having one form such as name,surname ,city, country,photo,ringtone.
I don't know which option i pick up from data storage option shared preference ,internal storage, SQ lite please help me i am having photo as JPEG format and ringtone as mp3 format rest as string thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Files like JPEGs and MP3s are usually stored in internal storage.  Strings are usually stored in the database.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If you don't expect the JPEGs and MP3s to change without updating your APK, you could provide them as resource files bundled with the APK.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: in my app i want to store photo and song that user chooses for his wish how i can do that

Comment: You're saying you want to remember which photo and song were selected?  If you have a DB already, I would store it there.  Otherwise, shared preferences are a simple mechanism.

Comment: lets take a simple scenario in which my app has a setting form in which i want to store user name,surname, photo,ringtone and user put his name surname, select photo, ringtone, and say save. these things are uploaded to my server OK.now whenever next time my app  start and user see his setting at that time above entered things are present there also whenever any message comes the selected ringtone must be rings